# OpenGL ES iOS tearing/flickering

Tags: ios, opengl-es, artifacts, tearing

I've looked around and none of the fixes for this type of issue is working on my particular OpenGL app. The problem is I get some type of artifacts/tearing/flickering on the model I'm rendering. The model is built up of small squares next to each other and the flickering is shown between these where there are glimpses of the background even though they are side to side. The problem is NOT showing on the iOS simulator but only on devices (I use an iPhone 5 and an iPad 4th Gen). I've tried the kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking setting both ways without luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be mesh trouble or z-fighting... hard to tell without a screenshot.

Comment: Like mentioned it could be Z-Buffer issue, well sort of. The thing is if you specify lowp or even mediump in the vertex shader for your position the floats will be less accurate than what your Z-Buffer could handle in practice. Try to set your position vec to highp in the vertex shader.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm rendering triangles, all on different z depths and still getting flickering in both simulator and device.